# rm: cannot remove directory/: Permission denied

Tags: permissions, rm

I made a directory called "shadi" and set this permission for it

```
sinoosh@ubuntu:/home$ ls -ld shadi
drwxr-xrwx 2 root root 4096 Jul  1 01:58 shadi
```

In this situation I have "others" permissions, but why can I not delete it?

```
sinoosh@ubuntu:/home$ rm -r shadi/
rm: cannot remove ‘shadi/’: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Here the problem is you do not have "w" permission on the `/home` directory.
While deleting a file note that you are not writing to that file but you are changing the contents of the directory that contains the file, so having "w" permission on the directory is a must if you want to delete any file from the directory.

[image: terminal screenshot of "ls -ld /home"]

If I am in a directory with "w" permission, I can delete any of its files without being worried about the file permission itself.
Note that my present directory is `/home/rohith` which has "w" permission and hence I can delete any of its files irrespective of the file permissions.

[image: terminal screenshot of removing /home/rohith/shadi]

If the same file is created in the '/home' directory which has no "w" permission I get the same output as yours ! :)

[image: terminal screenshot of trying to remove /home/shadi]

Comment: The restricted deletion flag or sticky bit 't' on a folder would also prevent deleting "it prevents unprivileged users  from  removing  or  renaming a file in the directory unless they own the file or the directory; this is called the restricted deletion flag for the directory, and is commonly
       found on world-writable directories like /tmp.  For regular files on some older systems, the bit saves the program's text image on the swap device  so  it  will  load
       more quickly when run; this is called the sticky bit."

Answer (score 26):

This happens because you don't own the directory, it is owned by 'root' and the 'root' group. So to delete it you can either changing the ownership and then delete it (here you elevate your rights and become 'root' for taking the ownership):

```
sudo chown $USER:$USER ./shadi
rm -r ./shadi
```

Or you skip taking the ownership and make a `sudo rm` to elevate your rights and become 'root' for the deletion:

```
sudo rm -r ./shadi
```

Comment: it means just the owners can delete files?

Comment: Yes, or you need to elevate your rights with the `sudo` command. this will ask for your password then and you become 'root' for the particular following command.

Comment: do you now if "shadi" was a file i can remove it with "sinoosh" user .it is not require "sudo " its not make scene for me why it does not work with directory

Answer (score 16):

Try this:

```
sudo rm -r ./shadi
```

The permissions show owner root and group root, so you have to use sudo.

Comment: Yes this command is ok, but my problem is why rm is not working with this permissions i have full permissions for this directory in other field

Comment: "i have full permissions for this directory" No you don't. "other field" shadi is not "others".

Comment: but "sinoosh" is belongs to others and he execute "rm -r shadi"

Answer (score 4):

## It's different accounts.

How would you expect safety from your account, if everyone had the permission to delete your home directory?

You do not have the `w` permission to delete someone other's home directory by default, except if they `chmod +w` it.

Here are the different permissions, and an example (`-rwxr-x---`/`rwxrx`):

```
+-+-+-+-+
|+|u|g|o|
+-+-+-+-+
|r|1|1|1|
+-+-+-+-+
|w|2|2|2|
+-+-+-+-+
|x|4|4|4|
+-+-+-+-+
|*|7|5|0|
+-+-+-+-+
```

It goes like this: `1 + 2 + 4 = 7`, `1 + 4 = 5`, `0 = 0`, so `750`, i.e. an ideal permission system. The owner (`u` in this case) can read, write and execute the file, the owner's group (`g` in this case) can read and execute, and anyone other (`o` in this case) cannot do anything. This is the legendary:

```
u: current user (User)
g: current user's groups (Groups)
o: not current user's groups (Others)
r: read permission (Read)
w: write permission (Write)
x: execute permission (X-ecute)
```

.

Comment: This table is wrong: r (read) is 4 and x (execute) is 1! (see `man chmod`)

Comment: Honestly this should be the accepted answer, I don't know how the accepted answer didn't realize that the guy was trying to delete someone's account.

Answer (score 1):

you must get root access first by:

```
sudo su
```

then force deleting the file

```
rm -rf ./shadi
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/793511/), except your answer is more dangerous...

Comment: BEST ANSWER for me. That "sudo su" permission was the key which was not mentioned in the above answers.