# Change owner and permissions of folder

Tags: command-line, 18.04

I have 2 users **test**(has access to sudo) and **testuser1** (has no access to sudo).

I need to make child3 and file.txt ownership and permissions only for testuser1 (which are created by user test)

```
/home/test/some_test/parent1/child3/file.txt
```

However when I do

```
sudo chown testuser1:testuser1 -R child3
sudo chmod 700 -R child3
```

I get

```
drwx------ 2 testuser1 testuser1 4096 Sep 30 00:39 child3
```

So I can't access to folder as another user (which is correct) but I can't also delete folder as **testuser1**, only **test** user can

Comment: `sudo chmod 700 -R child3` sets access rights to `drwx------ ` .. that is correct. What access rights do you want ?

Comment: @SorenA It's not about access rights maybe?, I can't delete the folder when logged as testuser1 using sudo su - testuser1

Comment: How do you try to delete the folder, and what errors do you get ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [rm: cannot remove directory/: Permission denied](https://askubuntu.com/questions/793507/rm-cannot-remove-directory-permission-denied) If not, please [edit] your question to show the permissions to the `parent1` folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is normal. You have set the permissions for `/home/test/some_test/parent1/child3` and files therein. However, that folder resides in `/home/test/some_test/parent1`. Deleting that folder involves changing `/home/test/some_test/parent1`. Thus, permissions of the folder `parent1` determine whether `testuser1`can delete (or create) a folder there.

If you want the user to also be able to delete the folder itself, you need to put it in a folder where that user also has write access (somewhere under the user's home folder is a good place).

Alternatively, you need to provide the user read+write access to the `parent1` folder, but that involves inevitably that that user will be able to rename and delete any files present in that folder.

The default linux file permission system essentially is rather basic. For more granular control of permissions, there is the feature of [Access Control Lists (ACL)](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/access-control-listsacl-linux/).

Comment: That was it! Thanks. The problem was that parent folder didn't have any permissions for others to write